# When using Assembly.LoadFrom on c# can't get const value from reloaded (and replaced) dll

Tags: c#, dll, assemblies

**What I'm trying to do:**

I am checking a version of data file, to see if the version is higher than the one that I have in a dll I referenced (DataVersionManager). If so I want to reload the dll from known path.

**Whats the issue?**

I use Assembly.LoadFrom and though it seems that the dll was loaded from path, when I try to get the const value, I get the old value (from the referenced dll).

As you can see in the image below, I try to put the value from the new loaded dll, "04.001.003" to the variable ver, but ver gets the old value "01.002.003"

**See Image**:

[image]

Comment: Crystal ball required again.  Never declare a `public const`, its value gets embedded in the code of an assembly and will retain its old value if you change the const but not recompile the assembly.  Use the `readonly` keyword instead.

Comment: If I use readonly, than I have to create an instance of DataVerMng. It dows'nt help - the value I get is still the old value.

Comment: Use a `static readonly` field not a `const` field AND recompile the code that is reading the version number.

Comment: Same result - Still getting the old value